# How to specify font attributes for all elements on an html web page?

Tags: css

When I set the font family, font size, color etc. it seems that some nested elements override these with ugly browser defaults.

Must I really specify those a dozens of times for any kind of element on my page, or is there a way to set them globally once and forever?

How to do that?

Comment: How exactly are you currently setting the font family, size...?

Comment: This answer should reside in the [default user agent stylesheet](https://meiert.com/en/blog/user-agent-style-sheets/), but I couldn't find in there.

Answer (score 315, accepted):

```
* {
 font-size: 100%;
 font-family: Arial;
}
```

The asterisk implies all elements.

Comment: This works, but it's not best solution. When the browser sees the '*' it loops over all HTML elements in the page and apply the CSS to them. Even for elements where the rule doesn't make any sense. Depending on the size of the HTML this can slow the page rendering.

Comment: Agree, but it applies the CSS to ALL elements, as BugAlert asked for. If one wants to effect ALL elements, one can expect the performance to reduce a little. :)

Comment: You can also add !important at the end of each style declaration to be safe against other style declarations outweighing this one.

Comment: I know it's been 5 years, but I'm surprised nobody has noticed until now: you should _never_ specify just a Windows font in "font-family" (unless of course it's a webfont) - Arial,helvetica,sans-serif is more compatible.

Comment: `html{font-family:Arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:100%;}body{font-size:1em;font-family:inherit;}` Font's inherit, and if you really want to avoid overrides use: `*,:before,:after{font-family:inherit;}` if you must use a universal selector, use inheritance instead.

Comment: THIS SHOULD NOT BE THE ACCEPTED ANSWER!!! fonts are inherited and you setting them on html/body is enough!. using '*' is very costly while constructing the render tree in the browser!

Comment: @AhmadBamieh mate, you are responding to a nearly 6 year old answer for a problem that existed nearly 6 years ago. What you are saying is most likely true now, but if you take a minute to read the OP you will see that at the time of writing, fonts certainly did not inherit to every element. For example, tables had the tendency to display weird browser defaults. Anyway, whatever you believe, but there is no need to shout at us.

Comment: @Bazzz true, i know its very old, but some people see the accepted answer and use it blindly, i just want to try prevent that from happening.

Comment: @CesarCanassa Good catch, but please offer better solutions , if possible.

Answer (score 24):

If you're using IE, chances are it will revert to the browser defaults for certain elements, like tables. You can counter that with something like the following CSS:

```
html, body, form, fieldset, table, tr, td, img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 100%/150% calibri,helvetica,sans-serif;
}

input, button, select, textarea, optgroup, option {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
}

/* rest of your styles; like: */
body {
    font-size: 0.875em;
}
```

Edit: you may want to read up on CSS resets; see threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset)

Answer (score 13):

I can't stress this advice enough: use a reset stylesheet, then set everything explicitly. It'll cut your cross-browser CSS development time in half.

Try Eric Meyer's [reset.css.](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: In order to use this reset.css, do I just link the stylesheet into my page or do I have to tweak it? I basically need to have the same font family and size across all major browsers. Does the reset.css help me do that by default?

Comment: I tend to copy and paste it at the beginning of my stylesheet rather than linking it separately, saves a HTTP request. It will help you set consistent styles across browsers because it zeroes everything: the only styles will be ones that you write.

Comment: Thanks! I did try it and it has solved most of my problems. However, I still can see a difference in font size between Chrome and Firefox in spite of my style sheet's specifications of the same. Any ideas about this? Also, is this a good practice?

Answer (score 9):

you can set them in the body tag

```
body
{
    font-size:xxx;
    font-family:yyyy;
}
```

Comment: This is not accurate because most browsers will not apply this font to some elements (the elements won't inherit the font-style)

Comment: @travis-146 what browsers? which elements? you know there is a spec that all browsers must follow.

Comment: @Bamieh one specific example (that brought me here, actually) on Chrome 72 is that it doesn't apply the font to text within a button or select menu.

Answer (score 3):

If you specify CSS attributes for your `body` element it should apply to anything within `<body></body>` so long as you don't override them later in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set styles of all elements in body you should use next code^

```
  body{
    color: green;
    }
```