# override font styles- every element of the page

Tags: html, css

i am trying to injecting font styles for web pages on a web browser.

to change every element of the page.

```
* {
 font-size: 100%;
 font-family: Arial!important;
}
```

in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942254/how-to-specify-font-attributes-for-all-elements-on-an-html-web-page) almost done the trick but this style get overridden. i want to prevent those overrides too. use of javascript to the solution is also ok.

Comment: Try tightening up your CSS rule like `html *{ blah; }` (I have no idea if that works in this context which is why this isn't an answer - but hey give it a go).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `!important` to the `font-size` declaration, too:

```
* {
 font-size: 100% !important;
 font-family: Arial !important;
}
```

If you are using this in a user style sheet (as the words “trying to injecting font styles for web pages on a web browser” suggest), then your rule cannot be overridden.

If, on the other hand, this is just part of an author style sheet, then it can be overridden by a user style sheet, and there is nothing you can do about it. It will not be overridden by a browser default style sheet, as they don’t use `!important`. With respect to other author style sheets, the cascade rules imply that you cannot be overridden except by a rule that uses `!important`, too.

In a fight between author style sheet rules that both have `!important`, the more specific wins, with specificity exactly defined by CSS specifications. Between equally specific settings, the one that comes latest wins.

The selector `*` has the lowest possible specificity 0,0,0,0. For any selector, you can always construct another selector with a higher specificity. However, a CSS rule inside a `style` attribute for an element is considered as having the highest specificity.

So if you know which other CSS rules will be used, you can beat them by adding selectors with a higher specificity in your selector list.

Answer (score 6):

If it got overridden, make sure it is the last thing in your style sheet (or the last stylesheet you include).  The "Cascading" in CSS means that last definition wins.