# Add CSS Transition to ALL my classes

Tags: css, css-transitions

Is there an easy way to add **transition: 1s all** to all the classes in my CSS file without having to add it to each one manually?

I was hoping i could just add it to the body and that would affect everything but it doesnt.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify font attributes for all elements on an html web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942254/how-to-specify-font-attributes-for-all-elements-on-an-html-web-page)  - Title mentions font, question applies though. That said, I can't help but feel this would be a performance nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following syntax to apply css to all elements

```
* {
transition: 1s all
}
```